# Pull to Refresh with WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to add pull to Refresh to WKWebView. Where in this code would I add something that would allow me to trigger pull to refresh? I haven't found any viable ways to add it to my code so you won't find any attempts by me to accomplish this in the code below. Most answers that I've found are in Objective-C or a language unsupported by my project.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class CycleViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        progressView.setProgress(0.1, animated: true)

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5"

        let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height))

        webView = WKWebView(frame: customFrame, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.containerView.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))



        progressView.sizeToFit()
        progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 204/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)

        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0196, green: 0.4, blue: 0.2902, alpha: 1.0)
        webView.isOpaque = false

        self.webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday")!) as URLRequest)

        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .new, context: nil)

    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            print(self.webView.estimatedProgress);
            self.progressView.progress = Float(self.webView.estimatedProgress);        }
    }

    @IBAction func home(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: UIButton) {

        webView.reload()

    }

    //This method will call when you press button.
    @objc func acButtonPressed() {

        print("button is pressed")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Account", sender: self)
    }
}
`
```

Comment: What's wrong with the Objective-C code you've found? It's the same APIs used by Swift. Just translate the code as needed using the APIs as a guideline.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nothing special about applying pull to refresh behavior to a web view, however keep in mind that you would need to add the `UIRefreshControl` as a subview into the web view `scrollView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // after done with setup the `webView`:
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadWebView(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

`reloadWebView` method:

```
@objc func reloadWebView(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    webView.reload()
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

---

**Tip:** instead of using `NSURLRequest` and casting it to `URLRequest` you could use `URLRequest` directly, so instead of:

```
self.webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday")!) as URLRequest)
```

do it as:

```
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday")!))
```

Answer (score 7):

Add `refreshControl` to `webView.scrollView` under `didSet` callback to `webView`

```
var webView: WKWebView! {
    didSet {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reload(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        webView.scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
}
```

And add this to reload `webView`

```
@objc private func reload(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    webView.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct but to use **UIRefreshControl** you need to be turned on `scrollView.bounces = true`. So the fresh code will be:

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = true
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

After that separate function:

```
func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    webView.reload()
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: At least as of today, webView.scrollView.bounces = true by default. But Apple can always change that ;)

Comment: I had to add this `webView.scrollView.bounces = true` line to make the code works. So thanks :)